# What is the quickest and most code efficient way to pull a number from a NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsrange

I have a number of strings like these. The numbers can be infinitely long.

```
<a href="?page=1">1</a>
<a href="?page=13">13</a>
<a href="?page=13121">13121</a>
<a href="?page=1389988797">1389988797</a>
```

What is the quickest and most code efficient way to pull JUST the number from these NSStrings?

Comment: which number? the one after `>`?

Comment: Yes, the one between the > and <

Comment: try this regex `(?<=>)\d+(?=<)`

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are 21 non-number characters in each of your examples, so the length of the numbers will be:

```
NSUInteger length = (string.length-21)/2;
```

the location will be:

```
NSUInteger location = string.length-4-length;
```

so a quick path to the digits should therefore be:

```
[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, length)];
```